# DropDownList Selection and table structure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

This is a a question that hard to explain and complicated. But I will try my best to describe it.

I have three tables   (Material, Test, Material_Test)

In Material Table,     it is like

```
MaterialID    MaterialName
     A         Plastic
     B         Wood
```

In Test Table, it is like

```
TestID    TestClass   Temp
   1         high     40
   2         low      30
   3         Medium   35
```

In my Material_test Table,

```
MaterialID   TestID  Min   Max 
    A          1     1.0    1.2
    A          2     1.2    2.2
    B          1     2.0    3.0
```

The last table records the the min and max test result of different material under different test.

I create one Dropdownlist ddl_material on the top of the page which used to binding all the material in the "Material" table. I create another Dropdownlist ddl_test which binding all the tests in the "Test" table under the ddl_material and the textboxs to show the related test "Temp", "Min" and "Max" result. what I want to implement is that after I choose one material from ddl_material, the ddl_test will show all the tests available(please notice here I want all tests not just tests in the Material_test, not like cascading, for example, for material A, there are only test 1 and 2 in Material_Test table but i want the ddl_test still have all the test including test 3). Then when I select from the ddl_test, if there is min and max value related to that material with the specific test I selected, those textboxs will show both "Temp" from "Test" table and "Min" and "Max" from "Material_Test" Table. if the test selected havent applied to the material, which means there is no records in the "Material_Test" table, then only the Texbox for test's "Temp" will show but no "Min" and "Max" should show.

I tried to using left join for the stored procedure, but the dropdownlist still not work as I decribed.

Any help will appreciate!! I will be very happy to clarity if there is any question. Thanks!!

```
SELECT 
   T.Temp
   M.Min
   M.Max      
   FROM 
   Test as T
   Left Join
   Material_Test as M
   On M.TestID = T.TestID
   Where M.TestID = @ID and M.MaterialID = @Material
```

Comment: Please show the SQL statement you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to bind test dropdown directly to records in Test table. There is no need to get the selected material. In the query where you are getting the test results, if there are no results for a particular test, you can hide the values.

Comment: Thanks. But how could I know if the result is for specific material.

Comment: You can get the material ID from the selected item in dropdown list.

Comment: I think you do help me somehow. To hide the value is a good idea. Thanks.